# Fix EXIF rotation info

Tags: windows-7, photos, exif

How can I quickly fix the EXIF data for photos that have incorrect orientation information? I don't wish to actually rotate the JPG, just fix the EXIF tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a metadata editor like [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en/) or [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to edit the EXIF information of your photographs.